# Internal server error when adding HTTP Basic Authentication to rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

I am adding a REST interface to a working RAILS 3.2 app that uses Devise. I enabled HTTP Basic Authentication and have my app sending the correct email and password. Using PUTS statements I see the controller action finishing and I see successful database updates in the log, but then there is an 500 internal server error. The next statements in the log show a Missing Template error (Missing template home/index...).

Logging in via the web site still works fine, so something is happening with the HTTP Basic Authentication.

Has anyone else seen this?

(I tried adding a new controller just for the API and got the same issue, the view is there but does not seem to be found)

```
Started GET "/api/login" for 192.168.0.198 at 2013-06-02 18:46:32 -0400
Processing by Api2Controller#login as JSON
[1m[36mUserLogin Load (169.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `user_logins`.* FROM `user_logins` WHERE     `user_logins`.`email` = 'me@gmail.com' LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36m (180.3ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE `user_logins` SET `last_sign_in_at` = '2013-06-02 17:36:18',`current_sign_in_at` = '2013-06-02 22:46:32', `sign_in_count` = 41, `updated_at` ='2013-06-02 22:46:32' WHERE `user_logins`.`id` = 12[0m [1m[35m (31.1ms)[0m  COMMIT

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 893ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api2/login, application/login with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json, :xml, "text/json", :js], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.        Searched in:
  * "/home/rob/Documents/testworkspace/Crosswords3/app/views"
  * "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.2/app/views"
):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
```

Comment: could you show us some of the logs?

Comment: Can you confirm that the template `login` exist in the correct directory. Also the format is JSON. Do you have the view for the JSON?

Comment: yep, the template login exists and is used when accessing the site from a web browser. I also tried changing the format to xml, same result.

Comment: Ok, so I create a basic rails app that had just a single MyUser model, tested it, added Devise, tested it, added HTTP Basic (following: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-HTTP-Basic-Authentication), tested via web then tested via REST and same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper answer, but my way around the issue is setup separate controllers for the REST API and then use inline code:

```
def login
   @currentUser = current_user_login
   @userInfo = @currentUser.userInfo
   render :inline => "<% @userInfo.Token %>"
end
```